# Animate with \ifnum is not switching between 2 conditions

Tags: animate

I'm trying to animate a sign that switches between 120 and 80, and the text switch accordingly as well. But I'm only getting 120 and

```
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
    \multiframe{3}{n=1+1}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tcolor{ifthenelse(\n==3,100,20)}        
        \begin{tikzpicture}        
        \foreach \i in {0,40,80,120,...,360}{% 
\filldraw [fill=red!\tcolor]  (\i:0.25cm) circle (1.5pt);
\node[draw=black,thick,shape=circle, minimum size =6pt] (rect) at (0,0) {
\ifnum\n = 100  
80
\else
120
\fi};
\node[black, right of = rect, align = center, xshift=1cm] (note) at (0,0) {
\ifnum\n = 100 
\tiny Hazardous \\ \tiny driving conditions
\else
\tiny Normal \\ \tiny driving conditions
\fi
};}
\shade[left color=black, right color=white, draw] ([yshift=-0.5cm] rect) rectangle ++(0.1,-1.2);
        \end{tikzpicture}


    }
\end{animateinline}
```

Update: I have a problem when I fixed n, there is a delay in the way the text switch after the red light switches to 100. I tried to fix it but I'm getting an ew error, content of the first frame must not have zero width.

```
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
    \multiframe{3}{n=1+1}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tcolor{ifthenelse(\n==3,100,20)}        
        \begin{tikzpicture}        
        \foreach \i in {0,40,80,120,...,360}{% 
\filldraw [fill=red!\tcolor]  (\i:0.25cm) circle (1.5pt);
\ifnum\n = 2 
\node[draw=black,thick,shape=circle, minimum size =6pt, label={Hazardous conditions}] (rect) at (0,0) {
80};
\shade[left color=black, right color=white, draw] ([yshift=-0.32cm,xshift=-0.06cm] rect) rectangle ++(0.1,-1);
\else 
\node[draw=black,thick,shape=circle, minimum size =6pt, label={Normal conditions}] (rect) at (0,0) {
120};
\shade[left color=black, right color=white, draw] ([yshift=-0.32cm,xshift=-0.06cm] rect) rectangle ++(0.1,-1);
\fi
};}

        \end{tikzpicture}
            }
\end{animateinline}
```

In this one, I'm trying to have the light flashes always.

```
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
\multiframe{6}{iFrame=1+1}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tcolor}{ifthenelse(\iFrame == 1, 20, 60, 80, 100)}

  \foreach \angle in {0,40,...,320} {
    \filldraw[fill=red!\tcolor] (\angle:0.34cm) circle[radius=1.5pt];
  }

  \ifnum\iFrame < 3
    \drawSign{Normal conditions}{120}
  \else
    \drawSign{Hazardous conditions}{80}
  \fi

\shade[left color=black, right color=white, draw] ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=-0.05cm] rect) rectangle ++(0.1,-1)node[right,yshift=0.5cm,xshift=1.5cm](col){
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{/Users/diana/Documents/Research/Papers/WFS/Figures/Animate/Sprite-car-front.pdf}};
\node[right,waves,xshift=0.15cm]at(rect){};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\end{animateinline}
```

Comment: Your `n` variable is misnamed (see the [animate manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf): `n` makes it a “real” number). It varies between 1.0 and 3.0. Therefore, it can't be `\ifnum`-equal to 100. Also, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. And please accept correct answers that have been previously given to you.

Comment: @frougon, thanks for figuring out. The choice of `n` for prefixing "real" numbers was perhaps unfortunate and misleading. At the time, I modelled the multiframe loop after `\multido` from the pkg of the same name, where `n` has the same meaning.

Comment: @Diana Please make your example code complete (MWE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, the `n` variable is misnamed for an integral type (it should start with `i` or `I`) and your code has *a lot* of errors. Next time there is no [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317), I fear I won't attempt to debug your code.

The error reported by `animate`:

> Content of first frame must not have zero width.

comes from the fact that you do:

```
\multiframe{3}{n=1+1}{%
  % [irrelevant \pgfmathsetmacro snipped]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Beside the syntax error, the first frame is effectively empty because the `tikzpicture` can't be created since its `\end{tikzpicture}` comes *after* the final closing brace of `\multiframe{...}{...}{...}`.

Additionally, your `\foreach` loop is very wasteful, as it draws ten times the whole figure. The following code fixes these errors and other things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% The 'minimum width' must be chosen wide enough for both labels, or else
% there will be undesirable scaling.
\newcommand*{\drawSign}[2]{%
  \node[circle, draw, thick, minimum size=1cm,
        label={[minimum width=3.7cm]above:{#1}}] (rect) at (0,0) {#2};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
\multiframe{2}{iFrame=1+1}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tcolor}{ifthenelse(\iFrame == 1, 20, 100)}

  \foreach \angle in {0,40,...,320} {
    \filldraw[fill=red!\tcolor] (\angle:0.34cm) circle[radius=1.5pt];
  }

  \ifnum\iFrame=1
    \drawSign{Normal conditions}{120}
  \else
    \drawSign{Hazardous conditions}{80}
  \fi

  \shade[left color=black, right color=white, draw]
    ([xshift=-0.05cm, yshift=-0.42cm] rect) rectangle ++(0.1,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Keep in mind:** don't try to interpret the output from TeX before you have fixed all the reported errors (e.g., mismatched braces).

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the errors, but I would appreciate It if you could explain the ifthenelse(\iFrame == 1, 20, 100), it has three values and not just 2. What I understood, is that the code is producing two frames and not just three. What if I want for instance increase them to 6 frames and for each frame I want \iFrame to switch to a new number

Comment: My code uses two frames because I only saw two different conditions : normal and hazardous. I can help with 6 frames but need to know what you want : 6 different speed limits and 6 different colors? A convenient way would be `\edef\tcolor{\ifcase\iFrame\relax\or color1\or color2\or color3\or color4\or color5\or color6\fi}` (this assumes `\iFrame` is between 1 and 6, both inclusive).

Comment: The light should be flashing for each case, so I need 6 frames, the first frame should show the number 80 while the color should be switching between 100 and 20 (multiple times preferred to show that the light is flashing) and then the number should be set to 120 and then light should be flashing. I tried this \multiframe{6}{iFrame=1+1}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tcolor}{ifthenelse(\iFrame == 1, 20, 100,1 20,100)}. But it only worked for  \ifnum\iFrame < 3 but not for the \else condition. The light freezed to 100. If you wish I can updated my post with the new code

Comment: `\multiframe{6}{iFrame=1+1}{...}` is okay. `ifthenelse()` takes 3 arguments, therefore the syntax in your previous comment is incorrect. For the flashing light, you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\tcolor}{ifthenelse(isodd(\iFrame), 20, 100)}`. In order to have 80 on the first frame, replace the `\ifnum ... \fi` block with `\ifnum\iFrame=1 \drawSign{Hazardous conditions}{80}\else\drawSign{Normal conditions}{120}\fi` (the space or end-of-line after `1` is important); all other frames will show 120 and “Normal conditions”.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is what you want; just trying to guess from your description. If you don't manage to obtain what you want with this advice, edit your question and clearly describe what you'd like to have on each frame.